# Ubuntu installation from usb

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, mac

I have installed ubuntu on my flash drive usb. I am using a mac. Once I plug it in, it asks me to  complete an installation. Do I have to do the installation to fully use ubuntu from usb?

I can click on quit and it lets me use ubuntu normally, so I am wondering what I have to do.

Also, I cant seem to make a wifi connection happen. Any help on that?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Welcome to AU! We would like to keep separate things separate to increase readability. Please open a new question for your WiFi problem and [delete](https://askubuntu.com/posts/529650/edit) it from this question.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu USB is designed as "portable" Ubuntu, but, if you want to use Ubuntu upon your Mac, then you'll need to specific the USB to function as installer, not as a "portable" version.

Comment: What do you mean by portable? As in I plug it in and use its basic features? Because I think I understand why I can't use wifi, its because the usb cannot connect to a wifi connection.

What do you mean by USB to function as installer? I am trying to get through the process of installing it, but I have no success.

To be honest, all I want from it for now is to do basic functions. I will have time to understand it after, but for now, I really need it for my c++ class and I just realised it cannot compile (g++) but I can't install anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The official Ubuntu website [provides instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) to create a bootable USB drive and boot from it. Did you prepare the USB drive and reboot your machine as described (or equivalently)?

Comment: I followed the instructions, but now I want to install it but I get the following message : "The creation of swap space in partition failed #6 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sdb) failed". I have partitioned my HDD into the main one for mac and for ubuntu I gave 40gb. Is there a step im missing?

Comment: If you don't want to know, how to set up a live system on a USB drive, which was your original question, we should not discuss that here. Look at [the community help for Ubuntu on Mac](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook) and [partitioning schemes](http://askubuntu.com/a/343370/171636) and, if necessary, create a new question.